Why am I getting this Storybook import error with RollupJS?
I have a turborepo with a react component library which I publish to NPM. Call it @myscope/react — it's bundled with CSS using RollupJS. And turbo has some good docs on publishing local packages here.
In the repo, I also have two apps, a website that uses the React component library and a Storybook. The components are imported correctly by the webapp, and TypeScript is happy even in the Storybook directory. But when Storybook runs, I get:
The requested module '/@fs/Users/{user}/mre/packages/react/dist/index.js' does not provide an export named 'MyComponent'

Why? I've looked at dist/index.js and it seems like it's exported, but is this a limitation of the module strategy that Storybook supports?
I've created a minimum reproduction of the error here.
.storybook/main.ts:
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-vite";

import { join, dirname } from "path";

/**
 * This function is used to resolve the absolute path of a package.
 * It is needed in projects that use Yarn PnP or are set up within a monorepo.
 */
function getAbsolutePath(value: string): any {
  return dirname(require.resolve(join(value, "package.json")));
}
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    getAbsolutePath("@storybook/addon-onboarding"),
    getAbsolutePath("@storybook/addon-links"),
    getAbsolutePath("@storybook/addon-essentials"),
    getAbsolutePath("@chromatic-com/storybook"),
    getAbsolutePath("@storybook/addon-interactions"),
  ],
  framework: {
    name: getAbsolutePath("@storybook/react-vite"),
    options: {},
  },
};
export default config;


Storybook package.json:
{
  "name": "my-storybook",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.2",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build": "storybook build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@myscope/react": "workspace:*",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "storybook": "^8.2.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chromatic-com/storybook": "^1.6.1",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^8.2.7",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^8.2.7",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^8.2.7",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^8.2.7",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^8.2.7",
    "@storybook/react": "^8.2.7",
    "@storybook/react-vite": "^8.2.7",
    "@storybook/test": "^8.2.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.15.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.15.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.7",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.8.0",
    "tsconfig": "workspace:*",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.3.4"
  }
}

vite.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})


I have reviewed this discussion and I proceeded anyway. But I would love to at least understand why this doesn't work.
Edit
For my esteemed colleagues voting to close my question without comment due to insufficient debugging info when I have linked a minimum reproduction GitHub repo, here's a screenshot of the error I'm receiving at http://localhost:6006/?path=/docs/example-mycomponent--docs

I would expect the component to render as it does at localhost:3000


The problem is your apps/storybook/package.json file uses "type": "module" and is built with vite so defaults to using ES modules, but your packages/react/rollup.config.js specifies a build output of format: 'cjs'.
All you have to do is change to format: 'es' and your problem goes away.
So you have to decide if you still want your previous cjs build, or es, or a dual build of packages/react.
Changing to format: 'es' is the simplest path. A dual build would be the next simplest, but I would recommend using exports in the packages/react/package.json to better support that. You can also probably get vite to support commonjs by adding a babel preset to the @vitejs/plugin-react configuration but I wouldn't take this path.
Dual build is the most versatile, but you probably really don't need CJS either.

Thank you so much! That got me past the import error to an issue with Rollup's use of the NodeJS crypto built-in... can you speak more to "dual building" and the advantages of CJS?

If you are intending to publish a library then it is generally favorable to support ES modules and CommonJS to be more user friendly. However, if your library is primarily targeted at browser-based clients, then my recommendation would be to only worry about ES modules. Either way, dual builds are not that hard to accomplish and might as well have your cake and eat it too if it doesn't come with too much overhead in terms of maintenance and a build. FWIW, whenever I publish a library I create a dual build.
